# Probability Mass Function making the Truncated Normal Discrete

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

I want to discretize the Truncated Normal to describe the spread in the Grades of students in a class sitting the same exam.

Let an arbitrary number of students sit the same exam. The grades are usually said to be normally distrubutted (they couldn't possibly be distributed with the truncated normal and much less by a simply normal because the grade are bound from both ends and are discrete).

The minimum grade is a parametre **a** (even negative grades are allowed)

The maximum grade is a parametre **b**

The minimum difference possible between two grades is a parametre **c**

**x** (measured in X axis) is the grade

**y** (measured in Y axis) is the probability of a student achieving X grade or the frequency that students in the class achieve grade X.

**μ** is a transformation of the mean, it is the mode if μ lies between a and b and is also the mean if μ lies halfway between a and b

**σ** is a transformation of the SD, it is the SD when $a\to-\infty\cap b\to\infty \cap c=0$

When $c=0$ we have a Truncated Normal

When $a\to-\infty\cap b\to\infty \cap c=0$ we have a Normal.

I want my distribution (f(x,μ,σ,a,b,c)) to meet some criteria

1 Being supported on the terms of an arithmetic progression. Both the initial and final terms and the common difference are parametres

2 Being unimodal in all cases but 1. Being bimodal in case the mode is equidistant from 2 values in the support.

3 Having probabilites strictly decreasing as X distances itself from the mode. The decrease in probability should be equal for x equally distant from the mode.
The change in the difference should first decrease and then increase after reaching a quasi-inflection point. The change in the difference should also be equal for x equally distant from the mean. I.e if the mode coincides with the midrange the distribution is symmetrical while if the mode is closer to one bound the distribution is symmetrical for all values closer than the nearest to the mode bound (short of like the Truncated Normal if you fold it at the mode all the values that are closer that the nearest bound coincide 1 to 1 and only what is further away does not coincide because there is nothing left for them to correspond to)

Hopefully the first 3 criteria are all compatible with each other.

4 If the above three criteria allow for it the distribution should belong to the Natural Exponential Family (better) or the Exponential Family (Plan B)

5 The distribution should be the Maximum entropy distribution that the above 4 criteria allow for (ignore criterion 4 if the first 3 make it impossible for the distribution to belong to the Exponential Family)

Such that the probability mass assigned to any point is proportional to the kernel of the normal distribution (leaving the mean and the standard error a parametre) calculated at that point.

E.g when a=0, b=25 and c=1

$f(0,\mu,\sigma, 0, 25, 1)\propto\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{{\mu}^2}{2{\sigma}^2}}$

$f(1,\mu,\sigma, 0, 25, 1)\propto\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left({\mu}-1\right)^2}{2{\sigma}^2}}$

$f(2,\mu,\sigma, 0, 25, 1)\propto\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left({\mu}-2\right)^2}{2{\sigma}^2}}$

$f(3,\mu,\sigma, 0, 25, 1)\propto\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left({\mu}-3\right)^2}{2{\sigma}^2}}$

**.**

**.**

**.**

$f(25,\mu,\sigma, 0, 25, 1)\propto\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left({\mu}-25\right)^2}{2{\sigma}^2}}$

of course

$\displaystyle \sum_{x=0}^{25}  f(x,\mu,\sigma, 0, 25, 1) = 1$

or more generally

$\displaystyle \sum_{x=a}^b  f(x,\mu,\sigma, a, b, c)=1$

What is the closed form solution (probably in terms of Theta functions)

Edit.

I am hoping the probability mass function I will get will be a conjugate prior (in the same probability family) that a posterior predictive distribution would be if we started with a discrete uniform prior (with a common difference c between each adjacent value in the support) where the random variable would be the individual students performance and each grade would be assigned the same frequency (if there are say 25 values in the support, 25 different grades possible, it would assign a probability of 0.04 for each grade) and the observations would be the individual performance of every student in the class (in the end we will have the performance of the class not simply their mean but an histogram). The posterior would be a distribution assigning a probability that a student randomly chosen scored X given that the class scored as the histogram shows.

I don't understand the difference between

$$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$

and

$$p_X(x) = \frac{\Phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu + 1/2}{\sigma} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu - 1/2}{\sigma} \Big)}{\Phi \Big( \frac{m - \mu + 1/2}{\sigma} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{1/2 - \mu}{\sigma} \Big)}
\quad \quad \quad 
\text{for } x=1,...,m,$$

Whuber said that they are not closed form solutions, because they involve an unevaluated sum. There is no closed form solution that doesn't involve Theta functions. I don't understand this either.

Comment: There is little justification in defining a pmf this way when compared with other functions from $\{0,...,y\}$ to $(0,1)$. The Normal density function is a density for a continuous variate and its values at a finite number of values such as the above integers cannot be interpreted as probabilities. In addition, most of the nice properties of a Normal distribution do not transfer to this new distribution.

Comment: @Xi'an The justification is simple I hate approximations. My data are bound both from below and above and much more significantly are discrete. I don't want a distribution which is easy to work with I want an acurate distribution (or the closest possible to that) even if I end up with something hard to work with. What other distributions f(μ,σ,x,z,y) are there (which are both discrete, and bounded from both sides). What properties do those distributions have that my constructed distributtion would lack?

Comment: In which sense an integer-Normal distribution is less of an approximation? more accurate? And what properties are you looking for in your model?

Comment: @Xi'an The properties I am looking for in my distribution would be having a discrete support, being bound both from above and below, being unimodal (or at worst bi-modal in case the mean is exactly in the mid-range between two points in the support), having probabilities strictly decreasing as X distances itself from the mode, being symmetrical if the mean coincides with the midrange (in this case with y=25 if the mean is 12.5). Hopefully the difference in probability would first decrease as we got more distant from the mean and then start increasing back when reaching a quasiinflextion point.

Comment: @Xi'an Hopefully it would also belong to the Exponential Family or better yet to the Natural Exponential Family. Furthermore it would be the Maximum Entropy Distribution out of the available ones (Meeting all the aforementioned criteria minus the impossible ;due to an inherent incompatibility of the other criteria and not due to maximum entropy, ones to meet). The data are sets of 25 answers to Multiple Choice exam questions. Others use Normal or Truncated Normal but in my opinion both are a poor fit for the data.

Comment: This question is confusing.  You repeatedly state you "hate approximations," but ironically you have yet to characterize the quantities you wish to compute!  All you have said explicitly is "I need a discrete distribution."  Could you characterize what you need in clear, mathematical terms so that people can know what might constitute an "approximation" and how to evaluate it? What do you mean by the "general problem" of which this might be one instance?

Comment: @whuber I don't want to compute quantities (with my question). I want to find the best fit for my data and construct a distribution.

Comment: Could you explain the sense in which "find the best fit" and "construct a distribution" differ?  And then what an "approximation" might mean?

Comment: @whuber There isn't probably a difference. I meant find the best fit in concreto and contruct a distribution in abstracto. The data best fits a single family of distributions. From the specific case a single distribution (the parametres would be estimated from the sample) I would like to abductively construct a distribution (analytically-parametrically) to use to all similar data. An approximation is any deviation from the facts motivated by ease to manipulate data. An example would be using a continuous distribution to describe data which are a priori knowingly discrete.

Comment: @whuber Another approximation would be using a distribution with an unbound support  for data which are a priori known to be bound. The is no negative height and many datasets are by construction discrete. When designing a multiple choice test a question is either Correct or Wrong there is no such thing as a half-right

Comment: That helps clarify things, thank you.  However, you seem to be posing a very broad question: namely, how to construct parametric families of discrete distributions supported on a specified set (such as the integers from 0 to 25).  And of course you don't want to construct the family based on the data: that would make correct inference impossible.  On what basis, then, do you want to construct the distributional family??

Comment: @whuber I would like to contstruct my distribution to fit my needed criteria. Based (loosely) on goodness of fit and descriptive accuracy. My question is how to construct a specific family of functions meeting these criteria.

Comment: @whuber The properties I am looking for in my distribution would be having a discrete support, being bound both from above and below, being unimodal (or at worst bi-modal in case the mean is exactly in the mid-range between two points in the support), having probabilities strictly decreasing as X distances itself from the mode, being symmetrical if the mean coincides with the midrange (in this case with y=25 if the mean is 12.5). Hopefully the difference in probability would first decrease as we got more distant from the mean and then start increasing back when reaching a quasiinflextion point

Comment: @whuber Hopefully it would also belong to the Exponential Family or better yet to the Natural Exponential Family. Furthermore it would be the Maximum Entropy Distribution out of the available ones (Meeting all the aforementioned criteria minus the impossible ;due to an inherent incompatibility of the other criteria and not due to maximum entropy, ones to meet). The data are sets of 25 answers to Multiple Choice exam questions. Others use Normal or Truncated Normal but in my opinion both are a poor fit for the data.

Comment: @whuber The difference in probability and the change in the difference would be equal for points equally distant from the mean. Unless of course the mean is closer to one bound which would make any such difference&change in difference disappear and the equal difference and equal change for probability would only hold for points that are as close to the mean as the nearest bound an example of a continuous(sadly) distribution would be the truncated normal. In case μ = (a + b) /2 it is symmetric while for all other μ the function is quasi-symmetric.

Comment: @whuber Folding the distribution at μ all the points to the nearest bound coincide with the respective points (as distant as the nearest bound). And also the first derivative is also kind of symmetrical the first derivative is maximised at μ while the rest is the additive inverse of the symmetrical. Last but not least the second derivative is also symmetrical in the true sense.

Comment: That information will be helpful to everyone thinking about your question, so consider putting it into the question itself.

Comment: @whuber How do you suggest I word myself when adding such information? Could you please suggest an edit adding this information? Also there is more information in the replies to the answer.

Comment: @whuber I tried but ended up with a word of text. I really don't know what information to keep.

Comment: @whuber I tried rewording the entire question.

Comment: @whuber Isn't the question now clear and unambiguous?

Comment: @whuber Please check my wording in the original question once more. I edited it to restrict it to grades.

Comment: Thank you, George.  But what is your question?  You state you want to discretize a Normal distribution and then you do just that.  What is left to say?

Comment: @whuber I want the closed form solution. Tyrel Stokes gave me a closed form solution (It is somewhat too specific with a=0 and c=1) and I don't know whether it meets the criteria I intended for it to meet.

Comment: He did not give you a closed form solution, because it involves an unevaluated sum.  There is no closed form solution that doesn't involve Theta functions.

Comment: It would be more natural to try a beta distribution, and or other distributions that have support on the finite range from a to b. It is unclear to me whether you are looking for a [discrete distribution with finite support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#With_finite_support) or a [continuous distribution with support on a bounded interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#With_finite_support). However, a left and right truncated normal distribution is certainly not the first thing that comes to mind, ...

Comment: cont... and, I have having a difficult time imaging how such a thing would be physical.

Answer (score 5):

The other answer here uses the normal density values at the exact points.  Another similar method would be to take the normal probabilities across intervals centred on those points.  In the latter case, taking the support to be $X = 1,...,m$ you get:

$$p_X(x) = \frac{\Phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu + 1/2}{\sigma} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu - 1/2}{\sigma} \Big)}{\Phi \Big( \frac{m - \mu + 1/2}{\sigma} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{1/2 - \mu}{\sigma} \Big)}
\quad \quad \quad 
\text{for } x=1,...,m,$$

where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.  You can then adjust to an arbitrary arithmetic progression by taking the appropriate linear transformation.  This has the first three properties you stipulated in your question.

Comment: What does it mean to "take the normal probabilities"? Does this pmf belong to either the natural exponential family or the exponential family? Is the entropy maxed out given the constraints? If we calculated the bayesian posterior given a discrete uniform distribution (with constant c) and normally distributed data would we end up with a posterior of this family; would this pmf be a conjugate prior to the posterior calculated with a discrete unifrom and normally distributed data? How much of a difference would it make to use this pmf as a prior rather than a discrete uniform (with constant c)?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Does it belong to the Natural Exponential family too?

Comment: @George I don't believe it does. Neither does the truncated normal distribution (if you do not fix $\sigma, a, b$ and $c$). The motivation/advantage of the distribution here would be that the cumulative distribution is relatively simple to express, it is exactly the same as the continuous truncated normal distribution.

Comment: What is the difference between $$p_X(x) = \frac{\Phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu + 1/2}{\sigma} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu - 1/2}{\sigma} \Big)}{\Phi \Big( \frac{m - \mu + 1/2}{\sigma} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{1/2 - \mu}{\sigma} \Big)}
\quad \quad \quad 
\text{for } x=1,...,m,e$$ and $$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a=0,b,c=1) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$ are they the same distribution just differently formulated?

Comment: @Xi'an you are right, silly mistake. I was erroneously thinking of the categorical distribution, which is in the exponential family, where the parameters are $p_1, p_2, p_3, \cdots, p_n$, and thought that would capture any other discrete distribution. But, then the parameterization is entirely changed.

Comment: What justifies the different method? What is the difference (for the better)? Does $$p_X(x) = \frac{\Phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu + c/2}{\sigma} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu - c/2}{\sigma} \Big)}{\Phi \Big( \frac{b - \mu + c/2}{\sigma} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{a+c/2 - \mu}{\sigma} \Big)}
\quad \quad \quad 
\text{for } x=a,a+c,a+2c,...b-c,b,$$ have a greater entropy than $$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$ Where $\Omega = \lbrace a,a+c,a+2c,\dots b-c,c \rbrace$ all the values in the support?

Comment: Can you please answer which of the 2 has a higher entropy and which has a higher variance (σ is just a scale parametre it is a transformation of the standard error)?

Comment: I don't know which has the higher entropy or variance.

Answer (score 5):

When you use the values of the normal density then you get automatically the first four conditions satisfied

$$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$

where $\Omega = \lbrace a,a+c,a+2c,\dots b-c,c \rbrace$ all the values in the support.

---

#### Maximum entropy

The fifth condition, maximum entropy, is also fulfilled since the maximum entropy distribution with constraints $\sum_{\forall x} x p(x) = \mu$ and $\sum_{\forall x} x^2 p(x) = \text{var}$ [must be of the form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy#General_solution_for_the_maximum_entropy_distribution_with_linear_constraints) $$P(X=x) = ce^{\lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 x^2}$$ which is like the distribution above (e.g. see that with $\lambda_1 = \mu/\sigma^2$ and $\lambda_2 = -1/(2\sigma^2)$ you get the above).

---

We can also prove it explicitly by considering the Kullback-Leiber divergence or [Gibbs inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%27_inequality) with another distribution $f(x)$, and our distribution $g(x)$

$$\begin{array}{} 
- \sum_{\forall x} f(x)\log f(x) &\leq& - \sum_{\forall x} f(x)\log g(x) \\
&\leq& - \sum_{\forall x} f(x)\log \left(ce^{\lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 x^2} \right)\\
&\leq & - \sum_{\forall x} f(x)\left(\log c + \lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 x^2 \right)\\
&\leq & - \sum_{\forall x} g(x)\left(\log c + \lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 x^2 \right) \\
&\leq& - \sum_{\forall x} g(x)\log g(x)
\end{array}$$

This second last step where we switch from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$ is because of the constraints
$$\begin{array}{}
\sum_{\forall x} f(x) &=& \sum_{\forall x} g(x) &=& 1 \\
\sum_{\forall x} xf(x) &=& \sum_{\forall x} xg(x) &=& \mu \\
\sum_{\forall x} x^2f(x) &=& \sum_{\forall x} x^2g(x) &=& \text{var}
\end{array}$$
with these constraints we can rewrite
$$\sum_{\forall x} f(x)\left(\log c + \lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 x^2 \right) = \sum_{\forall x} g(x)\left(\log c + \lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 x^2 \right)$$

So we must have that the entropy of $f(x)$ must be smaller than the entropy of $g(x)$.

Comment: What does it mean to "use the values of the normal density"? Does this pmf belong to the natural exponential family or just the exponential family? If we calculated the bayesian posterior given a discrete uniform distribution (with constant c between values in the support) and normally distributed data would we end up with a posterior of this family? Would this pmf be a conjugate prior to the posterior calculated with a discrete unifrom (with constant c) and normally distributed data? How much of a difference would it make to use this pmf as a prior rather than a discrete uniform (with c)?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos  "use the values of the normal density": it means that we make the PMF of the discrete distribution equal to the PDF of the continuous distribution, with only a multiplicative constant as difference.

Comment: The pmf belongs to a two-parameter exponential family (or five-parameters if you include $a,b$ and $c$). When you fix the variance then it will also belong to the natural exponential family.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos It is not clear to me what you are asking for with the Bayesian computations.

Comment: In what family does the posterior belong to when the prior is a discrete uniform (with a common difference c between each pair of adjacent values of the support) and the data is from a normal distribution (with unknown mean and variance)? Lets say the posterior is from X family. Does $$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$ belong to X family? Is $$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$ a conjugate prior to X?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos "the data is from a normal distribution"? What sort of data and which parameters of that normal distribution has the uniform distribution as prior?

Comment: I like your answer more than the one Tyrel Stokes (I liked his too I just prefer yours) gave me but I am seeing that $$f_X(X=x;\mu, \sigma) = \frac{exp(-\frac{(\mu -x)^2}{2\sigma^2})}{\sum_{y=0}^Texp(-\frac{(\mu -y)^2}{2\sigma^2})}$$ is just a special case of $$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$ with a=0 and c=1 I am not seeing any other difference but  Whuber said that  There is no closed form solution that doesn't involve Theta functions.

Comment: What is the difference between $$p_X(x) = \frac{\Phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu + 1/2}{\sigma} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu - 1/2}{\sigma} \Big)}{\Phi \Big( \frac{m - \mu + 1/2}{\sigma} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{1/2 - \mu}{\sigma} \Big)}
\quad \quad \quad 
\text{for } x=1,...,m,e$$ and $$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a=0,b,c=1) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$ are they the same distribution just differently formulated?

Comment: The uniform distribution would be a distribution of the grades of each student when the grades are between 0 and 100 (or 25) with no decimal then the prior would assume (believe or rather show the belief) that the grades are uniformly distributed with each grade having equal probability (0.04 or 0.01) and the data would be drawn from a normal when μ is the mean performance of the class. Intuitevely the resulting posterior should be of the same family as $$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos I still do not follow your Bayesian problem and which variable is being estimated based on what sort of data. Maybe you should put it in the question or create a new question.

Comment: The data points would be the grades of each student. In the end it will be the number of students that achieved each grade. (1 was achieved by 1 student, 2 was achieved by Z and so on)

Comment: Indeed my distribution is similar to Tyrel Stokes' solution. The only difference is that the parameters $a,b,c$ are incorporated and I have shown (intuitively) that the distribution is the maximum entropy distribution. The distribution by Ben is different, but approximately it is very close because with small steps (relative to $\sigma$) you get that $$\Phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu + 1/2}{\sigma} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu - 1/2}{\sigma} \Big) \approx \phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}\Big)/\sigma $$

Comment: No specific variable is estimated the posterior is calculated as an end in itself. It contains all the information available. Posterior calculated=Problem solved. I am just asking if such a Posterior (calculated from a discrete uniform and normal data) has $$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$$ as a conjugate prior. I am asking if instead of using a dicrete unform as a prior we used the "discretisized" normal if the prior and the posterior would belong to the same family.

Comment: The posterior is a probability distribution for a particular parameter. Which parameter?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability#Definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability#Example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability#Calculation The posterior would be the posterior probability distribution of the individual grades. It would be the conditional probability (conditioned on the wholle classes' performce) of a single individual grade/performance. Given that the class performed in the observed way it would be the probability that if we picked a random student they received X grade. I am not sure I would call it a parametre.

Comment: The mean of the posterior (the posterior would be a belief incorporating the evidence the classes' performance) would be the arithmetic mean of the students performance and the standard deviation would be estimated likewise. It would be a posterior for X (individual performance) neither for the Mean nor for μ (a transformation of the mean).

Comment: What is the likelihood function of the observations (and what do you observe?) based on which you update the prior into the posterior?

Comment: The likelihood function is a normal distribution and you observe the individual grades of each student in the class.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos but how does this likelihood function depend on X which is the parameter for which you describe the posterior. Say we have $$P(X|\theta)_{posterior} \propto P(\theta|X)P(X)_{prior}$$ It is not clear how you see $P(\theta|X)$, what are the $\theta$ and what is the likelihood function for the $\theta$? We need some observation $\theta$ distributed according to a distribution parameterized by $X$.

Comment: I did not understand the question. X is the individual performance of each student and θ is the performance (the whole distribution not just the mean) of the whole class. So the posterior would be the conditional probability of a random student having performed X (having received X grade) and the Likelihood would be the (joint) conditional probability of the class having performed (a distribution of the grades not just the mean) given on each student having performed $X_i$ (I guess it would be an histogram with X being the Grade and Y being the Frequency)

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos maybe you mean the [posterior predictive distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution)? It is best at this moment to write it as a question because I do not follow your logic viewing a distribution of $X$ as a posterior distribution. The Bayes rule is $$P(X|\theta)_{posterior} \propto P(\theta|X)P(X)_{prior}$$ and I do not see how your descriptions match this. The posterior $P(X|\theta)$ relates to the distribution of a parameter $X$ as function of an observation $\theta$ where these observations can be described by a likelihood $P(\theta|X)$.

Comment: So if you see a distribution of $X$ as a 'posterior distribution', then the $X$ must be a parameter in the distribution of your observations.

Comment: I am not very confident I have grasped the concept of a parametre of a probability distribution. I want my posterior to be exactly that a posterior predictive distribution. Predicting the probability that a random student will have grade X given that/conditioned on the class having performed as the Histrogram/Likelihood shows. The observations are the number of students having achieved grade X (or the frequency that grade X was achieved in the Class). If my observations are the frequency that grade X was achieved in Class is grade X a parametre it is measured in X ayis and is the main variable

Comment: @make it a question that makes it easier to follow and answer

Comment: @It is not a question. Surely not a separate/distinct one. So I added the information to this question here.

Comment: Can you please answer which of the 2 has a higher entropy and which has a higher variance (σ is just a scale parametre it is a transformation of the standard error)?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos which of the 2 what? This question is four months old and there are a lot of comments. I do not know what you are referring to.

Comment: One distribution is $$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{\Phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu + c/2}{\sigma} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{x - \mu - c/2}{\sigma} \Big)}{\Phi \Big( \frac{b - \mu + c/2}{\sigma} \Big) - \Phi \Big( \frac{a+c/2 - \mu}{\sigma} \Big)}\quad\text{for}\quad x=\lbrace a,a+c,a+2c,...b-c,b\rbrace$$ and the second is $$P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}} \quad \quad \text {where } \quad \Omega = \lbrace a,a+c,a+2c,\dots b-c,b \rbrace$$ which one has a higher entropy and which one greater variance?

Comment: @George Ntoulos It depends on the parameters but when the distributions have the same mean, variance and domain $\Omega$ then the second distribution has the higher entropy because it is the maximum entropy distribution for a given mean, variance and domain.

Comment: Then is there any reason to use the probabilities across intervals centred on some points instead of using the value of the density at those exact points? Is there any advantage to the different approach (using probabilities as a base instead of the density). Otherwise the second one (density-based) looks more elegant too it is not simply a matter of higher entropy. But is the variance the same tranformation of σ in both distributions when the other parametres (a, b, c, μ) are equal considering c is quitte large and a and b are finite?

Comment: about your second point: The variance and also the mean do not need to be the same given the parameters are equal (and it might actually be very difficult to find cases where they are the same although they should be close to each other). To find expressions to compute particular values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for a given mean and variance is not easy and there is probably no closed-form expression. However you can easily obtain values by fitting the distribution.

Comment: about your first point: an argument for the first distribution with probabilities computed across intervals is that for the points in $\Omega$ it has the same CDF as the continuous truncated distribution. This might be a desirable property for some.

Comment: The question regarding conjugate priors was: Let's say we believe (wrongly/mistakenly) that the scores of students in a test are uniformly distributed on $\lbrace a,a+c,a+2c,...b-c,b\rbrace$ so the prior $p(\theta)$ is that uniform while the observations have a likelihood $p(x|\theta)$ that is a normal distribution with unkown mean and unkown variance (we could estimate the mean and the variance but let's allow them to stay as parametres) and the normalizing factor is calculated as usual. Will the resulting posterior $p(\theta|x)$ belong to some of the above distribution families?

Comment: What are $\theta$ and $x$ in this story about conjugate priors?

Comment: I am basically asking for some calculus of distributions. I want to know the result of $p(\theta|x) = \frac{p(x|\theta)}{p(x)}p(\theta)</math><ref>$ when $p(\theta)$ is a discrete uniform (over the terms of an arithmetic sequence) and $p(x|\theta)$ is a regular normal (with the mean and the standard error left as parametres) and the normalizing factor accordingly calculated. Hopefully the resulting posterior would be the density-based dicrete version of the normal. My desired discrete version is a conjugate prior to the result of this calculus of distributions-based posterior (same family)

Comment: x are the individual scores of students in the class while θ is a parametre I don't even understand what means (genally) in a likelihood function. I never understood θ in my statistics classes. Not even on my Bayesian Statistics class (that is why a barely passed) Bayesian Statistics. What does θ generally mean on a likelihood function?

Comment: Maybe θ are the observed individial students' grades while x might be the general (observed and unobserved) students' grades. I am not sure what θ is in general.

Comment: if the likelihood is $$p(x|\theta) \propto e^{-a(x-\theta)^2}$$ and the prior is $$p(\theta) \propto e^{-b(\theta-\mu)^2}$$ then the posterior is proportional to the product $$p(\theta| x) \propto e^{-a(x-\theta)^2}e^{-b(\theta-\mu)^2} = e^{-a(x-\theta)^2-b(\theta-\mu)^2} = e^{-c(d-\theta)^2}$$ where you need to make the exact computation for $c$ and $d$ but you will know for sure that it is of this form because the addition of two polynomials is another polynomial of the same order as the highest order in the addition. So yes, the pdf in this answer is a conjugate prior distribution.

Comment: There are 2 calculi of distributions in my question. One where the likelihood is $p(x|\theta)=\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left(x-{\mu}\right)^2}{2{\sigma}^2}}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{{\pi}}{\sigma}}$ and the prior is $p(\theta)=U \lbrace a,a+c,a+2c,...b-c,b\rbrace$ and the posterior $p(\theta|x)$ is unkown (let's say f(x)) (it is the result of the calculus of distributions. And the other question (requiring a second calculus) is if that posterior resulting from the calculus before will be a conjugate prior to a posterior calculated from it (f(x) and a regular normal as the likelihood distribution.

Comment: What is θ and what does it generally mean on a likelihood function? Can we do Bayesian Statistics when there is no parametre of interest (we are not interested in the mean or the variance but only on the individual scores). We observe individual scores and we want to predict unobserved individual scores. What is θ and what role does it play? Can we calculate a posterior in such situation? How? What difference does it make in the algebra we must do whether we calculate a posterior predictive distribution or some posterior of some other parametre? Isn't it the same formula we must apply?

Comment: If we relaxed the restrictions of specified mean and specified variance (you said that the distribution is the maximum entropy distribution for a given mean, variance and domain) and only kept the domain fixed and as for the mean and variance only required a dependence on any location and scale parametres (we only want our distribution do be a function of location a scale parametres without specific mean and variance being given) what would be the maximum entropy distribution?

Comment: I don't want to fix anything. I want my maximum entropy distribution to be a function of these unspecified parametres. The entropy of this distribution for the same domain  $P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$  is lower than the entropy of this one $P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{2^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} 2^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$ And it gets higher the closer the base of the exponentials gets to 1 (but then the parametres don't matter).

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos If you don't fix anything, then the uniform distribution has the highest entropy. If you want something else then you need to add constraints like the requirement that the distribution has a particular mean or variance.

Comment: $P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{z^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} z^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$ has a greater entropy for the same σ, μ,and domain. σ Is just a scale parametre (a transformation of the standard error) not the standad error itself. So as z approaches 1 the variance also gets larger even thought the scale parametre was named σ (the 2 σs are interpreted differently they are different transformations of standart error)

Comment: But the uniform distribution doesn't have location and scale parametres at all (neither specified nor unspecified). $P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{z^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} z^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$ has a greater entropy for the same σ, μ,and domain. σ Is just a scale parametre (a transformation of the standard error) not the standad error itself. So as z approaches 1 the variance also gets larger even thought the scale parametre was named σ (the 2 σs are interpreted differently they are different transformations of standart error)

Comment: I would like to set z=1 but then I don't think the scale and location parametres matter any more. And if I can't set z=1 then it can be made arbitrarily closer to 1. There is always a number between 2 numbers. I don't want to lose my location and scale parametres (they can be different transformations of the mean and the variance no problem with the interpretation). I don't know what can I use for my likelihood (I want to make the least possible unwarranted assumptions)

Comment: *"But the uniform distribution doesn't have location and scale parametres at all "* Yes, but you wanted to have the maximum entropy distribution or not?

Comment: The maximum entropy distribution does not care but I do. Also I don't care about specific values of parametres. The specified mean is less worrisome than the specified variance althought I would like to lose both. I want constrants that are differently formulated. I only want my maximum entropy distribution to be a function of location and scale parametres without constraining it to specified values. You said and I quote "maximum entropy distribution for a given mean, variance and domain." and I want to loosen the restrictions of given mean and variance without losing my parametres.

Comment: I don't want to have the maximum entropy out of all possible distributions. I want given domain but not given mean and/or variance (I just want a distributions which are a function of those). e.g $P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{z^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} z^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$ as z approaches 1 the distribution becomes a uniform distribution (at z=1 I lose location and scale parametres). For the same values of the parametres the domain stays the same but the variance increases and the entropy increases too.

Comment: If you want a maximum entropy distribution that is parametric distribution then you need to impose a restriction on the probability distribution, like variance or mean. This doesn't mean that those variance and mean need to be fixed, they can be parameters that are allowed to vary. But for a given variance, given mean and given range, you will have a discrete variation of the normal distribution with given values for location and scale parameters.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. Please use as an example $P(X = x\vert \mu,\sigma,a,b,c) = \frac{z^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sum_{y \in \Omega} z^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}$ as z approaches 1 the variance increases and so does the entropy. Given the same μ,σ,a,b, and c the variance (and the entropy) gets higher the closer z gets to 1. I just don't want to set z=1 because then I get a uniform and lose my location and scale parametres (they no longer have any interpretation or significance) and I am in a double bind because I can get arbitrarily close to 1. Is there an alternative?

Comment: *"I don't want to have the maximum entropy out of all possible distributions"* if you don't want this then you need to specify how you want to reduce the possible distributions. Just saying that the distribution needs to have parameters doesn't do it.

Comment: I just can't formulate mathematically the restrictions I want to impose. The restrictions are given domain but not given (emphasis on given) mean and variance. In the example I used above the distribution is a distribution over location and scale parametres. But there is a different relation with the variance each time (σ is not the same transformation of variance for all z). I find it difficult to express it using natural language (formulating it mathematically is even more difficult).

Comment: For the same values of a,b,c,μ,σ the variance is higher and the entropy is also higher as z gets arbitrarily close to 1.  The relation of the parametres and the variance is different as z varies. When z is 1 there is no relation at all. I understand what given in our context of maximum entropy means. I understand that it does not mean the mean and variance are completely fixed. But when z in my example varies the relation of σ and variance also changes. What is the maximum entropy distribution for given mean (in our context of maximum entropy distributions) and given domain (but not variance)?

Comment: Theoretical I want to ask what stays given when z changes (consider it a fixed hyperparametre). z=e doesn't satisfy me I can do much better. neither does z=2. In the end nothing satisfies me because I can always get closer to 1 but never set z=1 because otherwise my μ and σ would lose their significance. I want a distribution with these two parametres still being significant but given μ and σ (not the exact mean and variance) the entropy should be the maximum possible.

Comment: The exponential function is a single parametre family.

Comment: $\frac{1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001^{-\frac{(x-μ)^2}{2σ^2}}}{\sum_{y\inΩ}1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001^{-\frac{(y-μ)^2}{2σ^2}}}$ is a 2 parametre family.

Comment: I don't understand why "Just saying that the distribution needs to have parameters doesn't do it."

Comment: What exactly happens when z diminishes from (1,e] and the rest of the parametres remain the same? Somehow the entropy increases without the distribution losing μ and σ. Probably mean and variance stop being "given" considering that when z=e the distribution already is "maximum entropy distribution for a given mean, variance and domain."

Comment: Z is not a scale parametre it is a fixed hyperparametre it controls the family in much the same way A, B and C do. And now I am confused. If base e already is a maximum entropy for given domain, mean and variance how can base 2, base 1.5, base ->1 also be a maximum entropy for given domain, mean and variance? When one changes z it also changes mean and variance. Aren't the restrictions different when z is different so that the distribution is a maximum entropy distribution? Otherwise only 1 of them would be the maximum entropy distribution

Comment: But z is fixed (it is an assumption of the model or otherwise known for certain) while σ is estimated (being a tranformation of the standard error). Z is fixed in much the same way a,b, c are fixed. I am not certain what you mean with a change in parametrization. I control z (I can set it to any value I like) while I don't control σ (I am estimating it). I am making dreaded assumptions to calculate my likelyhood the specific value of z would be one of them (under my absolute control exactly like a,b,c). Please explain what you meant with change in parametrization.

Comment: I appreciate the values differ in a different way when all else is equal (excluding z) and when all else is equal (excluding σ). I also didn't capture what was meant with fit σ and μ with z=2. Could I use $\frac{z^{-\frac{(x-μ)^v}{2σ^w}}}{\sum_{y\inΩ}z^{-\frac{(y-μ)^v}{2σ^w}}}$ to calculate/define my likelihood are more than 2 parametres warranted? I am interested in a posterior predictive distribution (and maybe a posterior distribution for the mean and variance) I would use this distribution (the observations are known to be positively correlated) for the likelihood and a uniform for a prior

Answer (score 4):

The most natural way would be as follows:

Let $X$ have support $0,1,...T$, where $T \in \{2,3,...,\}$ (i.e T can be taken as the limit to $\infty$, since the infinite sum can be bounded by the integral over the kernel of a gaussian pdf, but it will be intractable to work with in practice).

$$f_X(X=x;\mu, \sigma) = \frac{exp(-\frac{(\mu -x)^2}{2\sigma^2})}{\sum_{y=0}^Texp(-\frac{(\mu -y)^2}{2\sigma^2})}$$

This is a special case of the softmax function ($\frac{exp(z_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^Nexp(z_i)})$, which is commonly used to map the reals to the interval $(0,1)$ with the property that the elements sum to 1. There are many choice models which take this form, such as the multinomial logit, with $T < \infty$.

I agree with @Xi'an, however, that defining a pmf this way is unlikely to be justified. It is hard to imagine a principled construction of what this would represent and as Xi'an stated, the properties of a gaussian that make it nice to work with are not inherited by this new model.

Comment: The justification is simple I hate approximations. My data are bound both from below and above and much more significantly are discrete. I don't want a distribution which is easy to work with I want an acurate distribution (or the closest possible to that) even if I end up with something hard to work with. What other distributions f(μ,σ,x,z,y) are there (which are both discrete, and bounded from both sides). What properties do those distributions have that my constructed distributtion would lack?

Comment: reading the other comments, are you modelling the responses to each question i for data set j? Or the number of correct responses in each data set j?

Comment: Most probably the second. There are i students (and i exams) that each received the same 25 questions (different each year). The results are positively dependent (students who know/believe that they will do well tend to sit the exams more often, so on years with better teaching and/or a smarter cohort the sample is larger and the mean is larger too because of self-choice students themselves choose to sit the exam or not). I consider each year a different population (different students unless some failed and choose to retake it and different 25 question).

Comment: I want to infer 2 things a) how good was the performance of the specific student (my metric is [Their score / (The mean of all other students + The standard error of all other students)] and I take the weighted harmonic mean of the "Standardized" score between all their subjects. b I want to make inference on the Teaching that year. the mean might have dropped either because the test makers gave difficult questions or because the teachers taught poorly that year (or the cohort were stupid).

Comment: You could use a binomial model, where p_i is the probability of success for each class. If you wanted to try and separate the effects of teaching and the effect of the cohort it will be tricky. The two main approaches would be to find covariates with sufficient information to control for the strength of the class (maybe mark from previous year or gpa generally) and model p_i as an inverse logit which is a function of a parameter for the class and then the covariate information. The other typical route would be to model the selection process itself and use a weighted estimator.

Comment: But the data are not binary. They are not Pass/Fail. It is about how(quantity/magnitude) well that class performed on average on each subject (the teacher might be bad or used poor teaching methods that year, the test might have be difficult, the class might have been stupid).

Comment: each student can be modelled as from a binomial still. For each question, they either get the question right or wrong. If we suppose that conditional on $p_i$, the probability of a student in class i answering the question correctly, then each response within a student is independent we get a binomial with n=25 for each student. Now as mentioned before we model $p_i = logit^{-1}(\mu_i + X_i\beta)$. i.e, we model the probability within each class as being related to $u_i$ a parameter that helps set the class average and some covariates about the class $X_i$, like say grades in other classes.

Comment: Then you can back out the means for each class after the fact. This model does not assume that students pass or fail.

Comment: Again, to make the causal claims you would like it will still be tricky.

Comment: Binomial with known trials (here n =25) is exponential family as per some of your requirements above also.

Comment: and it also deals with concerns about being discrete over 0 to 25, and if it is not clear, the mean for each class will be $25*p_i = 25*logit^{−1}(\mu_i + X_i\beta))$. Using your estimates (which can be handled easily in any glm package, you can get estimates of the class means and then variance in a similar and construct your measure for how well each student did. The binomial can also be see as maximum entropy defined with respect to the mean or over suitable sets. https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/7/36891/files/2017/07/ech4-18a6gg9.pdf

Comment: I am not interested in each individual student. x_i is the number of Correct Answers student i got. X_i are certainly not independent they might not be linearly correlated but there is a strong positive dependence (the students are self-selected not randomized the teacher's transmissivity, the quality of the teacher's method, the difficulty of the test affect all of them, the students who know they will do well will sit the exam, usually a better teacher implies more confident students).

Comment: What I am trying to say is whether they got the specific question right or wrong is not important. I am not trying to model Bernouli Trials.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117219/discussion-between-tyrel-stokes-and-george-ntoulos).

Comment: I tried rewording the entire question.

Comment: Isn't the question now clear and unambiguous?

Comment: For me, my answer to your question is still the same and you didn't like it. To me, it makes more sense to model the data generating process directly and then compute quantities of interest after. In general, condition 1 will be hard to satisfy and may be extremely difficult in a way that makes sense with the data generating process. If you don't like that, then I would suggest looking at non-parametric estimators of your quantities of interest, however as I said before that won't fix your problem with controlling for the strength of the class without additional covariates and modelling.

Comment: But maybe someone else will come along with a different solution, who knows. Good luck!

Comment: I loved your answer. What made you thing that I didn't like it? You were the only person that gave me what I asked for. A distribution. I don't understand your suggestions to. 1. "model the data generating process directly and then compute quantities of interest after" and 2. "looking at non-parametric estimators of your quantities of interest, however as I said before that won't fix your problem with controlling for the strength of the class without additional covariates and modelling". What do you mean?

Comment: Could you pleast explain 1. what made you feel that I didn't like your question, 2. what do "model the data generating process directly and then compute quantities of interest after" and "looking at non-parametric estimators of your quantities of interest, however as I said before that won't fix your problem with controlling for the strength of the class without additional covariates and modelling" mean?

Comment: Just to make sure you understood my question. I don't want to make an inference on the classes' performance but I want to describe the observed classes' performance instead. I don't want inferential statistics but descriptive statistics. You could say the description is an end in itself. And that was all the question was asking about. I want this distibution to describe the performance. Probably the distribution I am asking for would be a conjugate prior to a posterior generated from a discrete uniform (with constant intervals) prior and normal or truncated normal data.